# Why doesn't Eclipse see my Samsung Galaxy phone even though I can transfer files using a drive letter?

Tags: eclipse, android

I developed my first (small) Andoid application using Eclipse and are now ready to transfer it to my Galaxy S mobile device (develping for Android 2.1)

Following another thread in SE, I changed the run mode in Eclipse to manual in the hope that I would be able to chose my phone and/or AVD every time I run the program.

The popup list howerver only show the AVD, my phone is not present in the list.

So obviously, my Samsung Galaxy S device is not recognized. Howerver, I can transfer to and from the device using a drive letter, so the USB connection is working properly.

Anyone any idea what I am missing here ? I'm not sure if it is an Eclipse problem , or a driver or ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929386/hardware-debugging-using-samsung-galaxy-s3-in-windows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to put the phone in 'debug' mode - I don't have the instructions handy (but you can search here or on the android site for the info you need)

Comment: Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging

Comment: @dpk - easier to remember next time if the OP has to find it ;)

Comment: and, apparently, useless to the OP anyway.

Comment: I have put the phone in USE debugging mode as you said (follogin DPK's advice), but still, if I press Ctrl-F11 from within Eclipse, the list of available Android devices is empty.  Any more ideas ?

Comment: never mind my last comment :) I figured it out myself - once I had installed KIES, the device was recognized by Windows and by Eclipse. I thought KIES was just some sort of transfer program - let's call it our version of iTune - but appearantly, it installs more than just that. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think you should answer your own question if you solved the problem. I had the exact same problem and it wasn't easy to spot the solution in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue with Eclipse on a Mac OS X. Simply putting the phone in 'debug' mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging) did not solve the issue. I have to do below in the command line to solve the issue.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the problem of eclipse not detecting my xperia x10.I installed sony ericson PC companion, the problem is fixed now. Seems some drivers specific to the manufacturer of the device is required.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking, you don't need to install the bloat. Go to: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535RWBVZW

Click on "Manuals & Downloads" and then "Software" under that.

Comment: This really works. Thanks Savas. I earlier used kies to fix this issue. However, currently I don't want to install kies for just drivers. I ended up with your solution. pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems connecting to my S5 from my Linux laptop (after enabling USB Debugging) - I found this guy's post really helpful!

https://androidonlinux.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/setting-up-adb-on-linux/