# Hardware debugging using Samsung Galaxy S3 in Windows

Tags: android, adb

Picked up my S3 on launch and want to get started learning to develop for android using Eclipse. So far I'm having fun!

However, I want to be able to debug my application on the phone hardware itself and not just in an AVD. My problem is that I cannot find appropriate USB device drivers. The Samsung support site is garbage and windows update told me 'where to go'.

Has anyone got this working yet? If so, how?

Comment: You need device driver software or something else?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For those still looking, you don't need to install the bloat. Go to:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I535RWBVZW

Click on or scroll to "Manuals & Downloads" and then USB (Driver) is available under "Downloads".

Direct download link: [Samsung USB Driver - 1.5.45.00](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201602/20160217043054798/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.45.00.exe)

Comment: the trick is to click on "software" - I kept missing that :) +1

Comment: Don't be dismayed when the web page shows Verizon and you have a Sprint phone. I installed this SAMSUNG driver just fine and can debug on my Sprint G3 just fine.  Thanks Honeal!!

Comment: There is a newer version of the driver available now.  The direct download link provided here is for 1.5.14 whereas if you click on the first link, it will take you to the product page where you can download the most recent version.

Comment: Updated the direct download link. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Turns out you have to install Samsung Kies to get the USB driver. Similar to the iPhone. I wanted to avoid this unnecessary bloat (i plugged my phone in and it threw a WPF exception...) and thankfully you can uninstall Kies without uninstalling the driver. Result.

After that, ADB is able to see the phone with no problem at all and I can debug on the device perfectly.

Comment: KIES is not actually necessary, there are other tools available

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes so far after the fact? I answered my own question with _the solution that actually worked_ and changed the correct answer to the leanest one when that became apparent.

Comment: the snowball keeps rolling, that's why dude, people keep coming from Google and other places, and your answer isn't acceptable anymore. That's one of the nicest things at SO, your answer might have been right for a period, but it's not anymore. SO dynamically adjust so other ppl get better answers when looking for the same troubles in different timeframes.

Comment: @RafaelRoman Negative. It is correct as it solves the problem. It is acceptable because it meets SO's criteria for answers. However, it is not the _the best_, which is why it doesn't have a shiny green tick next to it. "answer is not useful" - really though?

Answer (score 3):

you need the usb driver for it. Once you have that installed simply connect the phone via usb to your machine, start eclipse and adb will pick up the device given that the drivers installed properly. try this link, one of these will probably have the driver. [Samsung Galaxy S3 downloads](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9300MBDBTU-downloads?isManualDownload=true)

Comment: +1 because that link took me to a useful page. No driver there but I had been looking for it.

Comment: cheers, if you find the driver please share the link. I found with some of my devices that if I cannot find the driver it is usually bundled in with the manufacurers sync or other software.

Answer (score 2):

Can be downloaded on the following link

http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/ASPS/JSP

Comment: ... and if your PC is running Win7, you will need to right-click and "Run As Administrator" when trying to install it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for KIES or other bloat!!

There's a very useful toolkit that does much more then kies, and it's available here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1703488

Comment: Very useful indeed. I used this toolkit to root and flash my firmware to stock. It does indeed come with the drivers and a tiny footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Direct link from Samsung's Downloads section:
http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=US&CttFileID=5301407&CDCttType=SW&ModelType=C&ModelName=SCH-I535RWBVZW&VPath=SW/201211/20121110030255344/Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.exe