# Eclipse Will Not Recognize Galaxy S 2 When Debugging Even Though It Will Recognise My Touch and Run The App

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a java beginner. I am going through a book right now actually called Java in 24 Hours sixth edition by Rogers Cadenhead learning java and android programming. Anyways, to my problem. I am using eclipse to make a simple app and I want to transfer it to my galaxy s 2. I am ready to debug it and pick my device.... except its not there. I have installed Kies, the drivers, made sure its in USB debug mode but it will not recognize it. Any suggestions? This is not a duplicate! It is different because even though its in debugging mode, even though Ive reinstalled kies twice, even though Ive made sure the USB port or cord is not a problem it still does not work! But whats strange is my My Touch will work perfectly with the app. What am I missing here? This is the third time I have asked about this and cant find an answer. HELP PLEASE.

Comment: What OS is your PC running? And what does it say if you run 'adb devices' from a command prompt?

Comment: I am using Windows XP 64 bit. when I go to run my device from the list, its just not there.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no definite answer for these kinds of problems all I can offer is a list of things to try:

-Make sure the phone has the "Developer Settings": "USB debugging" and "Install app from unknown sources"

-Restart adb (from command line: "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server"

-Restart Eclipse

-Restart phone

-Restart computer

-Try a different cable

Sorry I cant be more specific, I have these kinds of problems with my S3 and S1 and it seems to have random causes and random solutions

You might also find some answers here:
[Why doesn't Eclipse see my Samsung Galaxy phone even though I can transfer files using a drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908301/why-doesnt-eclipse-see-my-samsung-galaxy-phone-even-though-i-can-transfer-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This may be of benefit:

> How to Install ADB Drivers for Samsung Galaxy S2
>
> Step 1: Disconnected my phone from USB
>
> Step 2: Using USBDeview, I deinstalled all previously installed
>   drivers relating to the phone (Careful here!)
>
> Step 3: Installed Samsung Kies, and loaded it
>
> Step 4: From Samsung Kies, I selected Tools > Install Driver (This
>   step took a while, and it seemed like it had stalled?Be patient!)
>
> Step 5: Connected my phone to USB
>
> Step 6: The devices installed?Windows then gave me an error
>   regarding missing drivers, however, when I checked device manager, I
>   could see "Samsung Android Phone" under which was "Samsung Android ADB
>   Device"
>
> Step 7: Then ran "adb.exe devices" (From a command prompt adb.exe
>   lives in the android-sdk folder)

[From here](http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/how-to-set-up-install-android-adb-usb-driver,30261.html) and [look here too.](http://naturalprogression.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/samsung-galaxy-s2-adb-device-driver/)