# Can't run android junit tests on a real device

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm running an Android test project from eclipse. The project run on the emulator. If I attach my device eclipse doesn't give me the choice to run the test project on it, but I can run my application on it from eclipse. Is there some setting I need to change to run test projects on   a phisical device?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special setting in eclipse.

There is however the "Developer Settings" in the phone.

You need to make sure that this is turned on and you may also wish to make sure that "USB debugging" and any "All code from unknown sources" settings are also on.

If this still doesnt work then you are likely having a ADB based problem so some of the steps mentioned here might help.

[Eclipse Will Not Recognize Galaxy S 2 When Debugging Even Though It Will Recognise My Touch and Run The App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948445/eclipse-will-not-recognize-galaxy-s-2-when-debugging-even-though-it-will-recogni/14948868#14948868)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was in the manifest: I was using <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" /> and I have android 4.1.2 on the phone. I thought the device manager would show at list show the phone as disabled but without minSdkVersion it doesn't show it.